# Creating a page of text in flexdashboard R

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have created a three page flexdashboard with 3-4 tabs within each page (utilizing rmarkdown). My goal is to include a dashboard overview page that has a description on how to navigate the application and information on how to contact me. However, I haven't figured out how I can insert something that looks like a typical rmarkdown format into flexdashboard? When I look at formats for flexdashboard they only include charts ie code chunks. Is there a way to include a few paragraphs of text with headers, bullets, and links into a flexdashboard page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty similar to markdown. Here's an example with 3 tabs & text in the first tab - it has a header, text, a link, and bullets:

````
Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Text

#### this is a header
This is text [link](http://www.example.com)

- one
- two 
- three



### Table

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

### Plot

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thank you